# How to fix the error code of object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Tags: r

I first started with developing a SMA moving average but I wanted to adapt the function to initiate a stock name from the user
here is my code below

```
library(quantmod)

    library(TTR)
    library(PerformanceAnalytics)
    stock = readline("Enter the stock name:")
    stock
    getSymbols(stock, src = 'yahoo', from = '2021-01-01')
    
    barChart(as.name(stock), theme = chartTheme('black'))
    
    # Creating Leading and Lagging Technical Indicators
    
    # a. Simple Moving Average (SMA)
    
    # 1. stock
    sma10_stock <- SMA(as.name(stock)$as.name(stock.Close), n = 10)
    sma15_stock <- SMA(as.name(stock)$as.name(stock.Close), n = 15)
    lineChart(as.name(stock), theme = chartTheme('black'))
    addSMA(n = 10, col = 'blue')
    addSMA(n = 15, col = 'orange')
    legend('left', col = c('green','blue','orange'),
           legend = c('stock','SMA10','SMA15'), lty = 1, bty = 'n',
           text.col = 'white', cex = 0.8)
    
    # Creating Trading signal with Indicators
    
    # SMA 
    
    # a. stock
    # SMA 10 Crossover Signal 
    sma10_stock_ts <- Lag(
      ifelse(Lag(Cl(as.name(stock))) < Lag(as.name(stock)) & Cl(as.name(stock)) > sma10_stock,1,
             ifelse(Lag(Cl(AMC)) > Lag(sma10_stock) & Cl(AMC) < sma10_stock,-1,0)))
    sma10_stock_ts[is.na(sma10_stock_ts)] <- 0
```

Comment: You can't use `as.name(stock)` to turn a string into the value of that object. `as.name` will return a symbol, not the actual data stored under that symbol's name. If you want to get a value using a string use `get(stock)`. Or, even better, try `data <- getSymbols(stock, src = 'yahoo', from = '2021-01-01', auto.assign=FALSE)` and then the result should be stored in `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MrFlick mentioned you can pass character value of stock in `getSymbols` with `auto.assign = FALSE`. To use `SMA` function you'll not be able to use `$stock.Close`, you can replace it with column number instead.

```
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

stock = readline("Enter the stock name:")

data <- getSymbols(stock,src = 'yahoo', from = '2021-01-01', auto.assign = FALSE)
barChart(data, theme = chartTheme('black'))

# Creating Leading and Lagging Technical Indicators

# a. Simple Moving Average (SMA)

# 1. stock
sma10_stock <- SMA(data[, 4], n = 10)
sma15_stock <- SMA(data[, 4], n = 15)
lineChart(data, theme = chartTheme('black'))
addSMA(n = 10, col = 'blue')
addSMA(n = 15, col = 'orange')
legend('left', col = c('green','blue','orange'),
       legend = c('stock','SMA10','SMA15'), lty = 1, bty = 'n',
       text.col = 'white', cex = 0.8)
```